# How can I sort on two digits instead of one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var options = $('select#myshp_search_field_7 option');
    var arr = options.map(function(_, o) {
        return {
            t: $(o).text(),
            v: o.value
        };
    }).get();
    arr.sort(function(o1, o2) {
        return o1.t > o2.t ? 1 : o1.t < o2.t ? -1 : 0;
    });
    options.each(function(i, o) {
        console.log(i);
        o.value = arr[i].v;
        $(o).text(arr[i].t);
    });
});
```

So this sorts my select field but it only sorts on the first digit(number)>

```
<select id='myshp_search_field_7'>
    <option value='10'>10</option>
    <option value='5'>5</option>
    <option value='3'>3 </option>
    <option value='11'>11 </option>
</select>
```

The result of the code is : 10 , 11 , 3, 5

But i want it to be : 3, 5 , 10, 11

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is because you are comparing string values. To correct this coerce the values in the `sort()` logic to integers using `parseInt()`:

```
arr.sort(function(o1, o2) {
  var o1t = parseInt(o1.t, 10), o2t = parseInt(o2.t, 10);
  return o1t > o2t ? 1 : o1t < o2t ? -1 : 0;
});
```

Also note that you can simplify the sort logic as you can work directly on the `option` elements themselves without having to first `map()` an array of objects from them. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myshp_search_field_7 option').sort(function(a, b) {
    var aVal = parseInt($(a).val(), 10), bVal = parseInt($(b).val(), 10);
    return aVal > bVal ? 1 : aVal < bVal ? -1 : 0;
  }).appendTo('#myshp_search_field_7');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="myshp_search_field_7">
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
</select>
```

Comment: thanks! , Do you also know what I should do when i have a string that contains a number ?

Comment: In that case I'd suggest parsing the string. There should be lots of questions covering that alreayd, if you search

Answer (score 1):

Use parseInt for a number sort:

```
arr.sort( (a, b) => parseInt(b, 10) - parseInt(a, 10) )
```

Comment: no need of parsing it.
arr.sort( (a, b) => a - b )

Answer (score 1):

You could use just the delta, which operands are casted to number by using the minus operator.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myshp_search_field_7 option').sort(function(a, b) {
        return $(a).val() - $(b).val();
    }).appendTo('#myshp_search_field_7');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="myshp_search_field_7">
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
</select>
```